# How to copy Mathematica code with subindices in a readable way?

Tags: formatting

I'm trying to post some Mathematica code that makes heavy use of indices on a blog, and when copying and pasting I end up with unreadable stuff like

```
Cos[Subscript[\[Theta], 0] + \[Tau]] Sin[Subscript[\[Phi], 0] - L], 
Sin[Subscript[\[Theta], 0] + \[Tau]] Sin[Subscript[\[Phi], 0] - L], 
 Cos[Subscript[\[Phi], 0] - L]}, {\[Tau], 0, 
 L /Sin[Subscript[\[Phi], 0] - L]}
```

Is there any way to copy heavily subindexed code like this in a readable format? Even if it is then impossible to paste back and execute, I'd rather prefer the code to be readable and provide an executable copy.

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ImportingAndExporting.html#25808 and also see [`MathMLForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MathMLForm.html) and [`TeXForm`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TeXForm.html).

Comment: I was expecting that, maybe, there was some way to export these subscripts as UTF-8 characters. There's no need to be pedantic -- if I already knew how to do it I wouldn't be asking in the first place.

Comment: `There's no need to be pedantic` I am not being pedantic, I am giving you the options you could try. But will delete my comment now since you do not like it.

Comment: I think unicode has subscripts for 0 to 9, but not other characters. Try searching here for 'subscript' https://unicode-table.com/en/

Comment: `unicodesubs[Subscript[x_, i_]] := StringJoin[ToString[x], FromCharacterCode[16^^2080 + i]]` this will 'work' for subscripts from 0 to 9 and nothing else, for example `subs[Subscript[x, 2]]`. No warranty!

Comment: @Nasser Saying stuff like 'What else did you expect?' to someone posting a question is as pedantic as it gets, and is in no way useful to no one. Even more, deleting the comment, which contained some other useful remarks that now no one can read, is childish.

Comment: @flinty Thanks! I know that not all subscripts are supported, but I only used single-digits subscripts -- I will try that out.

Comment: Hey I can appreciate Nasser's frustration - `Subscript`, `SubscriptBox`, and related presentational forms are the cause of much dodgy code posted on this site and lead to nothing but trouble. You should avoid them almost everywhere as a rule of thumb.

Comment: Now you are not just being ungrateful for free advice being given, you are also being rude as well. I asked you what else did you expect in order to see what is it you want as that is the plain text version of Subscript. There can be nothing else. I wonder sometime why bother giving free help here if this is what one gets in return.

Comment: @flinty Fair enough, I used them since they make my formulas look closer to mathematical notation, but I can now get why they can be a nuisance. Thanks!

Comment: @Nasser Giving 'free help' does not give you a free pass to post rude comments -- which, by the way, no one can read now since you deleted them after I pointed out they were.

Comment: There is nothing rude about asking someone "what else did you expect". You are the one who is rude here, not me. I gave you lots of alternatives options as well trying to help you.

Comment: @FernandoMartin why not just [embed your notebook/notebook cells](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframNotebookEmbedder/examples/)?

Comment: @CATrevillian: Thanks, didn't know about that!